# Kinds of IPI for x86 architecture in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, x86-64, interrupt, interrupt-handling, smp

I would like to know what are the different kinds of IPIs available for x86_64 in Linux. In particular, I want to find out the different interrupts handlers for IPI interrupts.

In Understanding the Linux Kernel, 3rd Edition by Daniel P. Bovet, Marco Cesati
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/understanding-the-linux/0596005652/ch04s06.html
lists three kinds of IPIs:

```
CALL_FUNCTION_VECTOR
RESCHEDULE_VECTOR
INVALIDATE_TLB_VECTOR
```

However in the latest kernels, I find the below comment in arch/x86/include/asm/entry_arch.h.

```
 * This file is designed to contain the BUILD_INTERRUPT specifications for
 * all of the extra named interrupt vectors used by the architecture.
 * Usually this is the Inter Process Interrupts (IPIs)
 */

/*
 * The following vectors are part of the Linux architecture, there
 * is no hardware IRQ pin equivalent for them, they are triggered
 * through the ICC by us (IPIs)
```

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/entry_arch.h?h=v5.6.15

Could someone confirm whether all those Vectors listed in the file are different kinds of IPI for x86_64.
For ARM I could find a unified handler - handle_IPI() for all the IPIs. A switch case is used to find out which IPI.

Answer (score 8):

On x86 *any* interrupt vector can be triggered by an IPI, so there isn't (or aren't) a designated interrupt vector.

[image: The IPI delivery mode and vector field]

The image above depicts the format of the register used to send IPIs, the *Fixed* mode uses the *Vector* field to make the target CPUs execute the interrupt service routine associated with that vector. It's like an `int vector` instruction was executed in the targets.

So Linux can, theoretically, directly invoke any interrupt on any other CPU.
However, kernel modules often need to run a function on specific CPUs; so Linux has a set of utility functions like [smp_call_function_single](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/smp.c#L269) that will make the life of the programmer easy.
These functions are implemented with a mechanism that's worth a chapter on its own, now I don't know the detail but it's not hard to image the basic idea behind: have a global queue of functions to execute and an interrupt vector that, once invoked, dequeues an item and executes it.
By calling that interrupt vector with an IPI, Linux can make the target CPUs execute the given function.

The interrupt vectors you found are used for this. You probably want to look at their 64 bits counterpart in [entry_64.S](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#L820) and under the guard `#ifdef CONFIG_SMP`.
The [`acpiinterrupt` and `acpiinterrupt3`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#L797) are just macros that define a label with the second argument, call `interrupt_entry` with the first argument (the vector number) NOTted  and call the function named in the third argument.
Be careful that the 32 bits analog does some nasty prefix-concatenation with the target function name.

`apicinterrupt CALL_FUNCTION_SINGLE_VECTOR  call_function_single_interrupt  smp_call_function_single_interrupt` is roughly equivalent to defining the function:

```
;Metadata stuff (e.g. section placement)

call_function_single_interrupt:               ;<-- first arg
  push ~CALL_FUNCTION_SINGLE_VECTOR           ;<-- second arg
  call interrupt_entry

  ;other stuff (tracing, flags, etc)
  call smp_call_function_single_interrupt     ;<-- third arg

  ;other stuff (like above, plus returning)
```

The vector numbers are defined in [irq_vectors.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/include/asm/irq_vectors.h#L70) and are, of course, also used in [idt.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/idt.c#L110) for the IDT.

The target functions (the interrupt handlers) are mostly (all? I didn't check) defined in [smp.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/smp.c#L247) and they probably are the closest thing to the ARM's `handle_IPI` handler.

Those seem to be the only vectors invoked through an IPI.

Comment: I know I am quite late to this, but thanks a lot. Your explanation helped me understand better how IPIs are implemented and solve the issue I was facing. Cheers!